Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This connector was made for Scala null, it was not meant to run on Scala 2.12
The pointed error code as follow
String strJsonContent = SessionContext
  .getSparkSession()
  .read()
  .json(filePath)
  .toJSON()
  .first();

And I'm using Maven to build the package without dependencies. pom.xml properties like below
<scala.version>2.12.1</scala.version>
<scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
<jsonpath.version>2.4.0</jsonpath.version>
<hadoop-core.version>1.2.1</hadoop-core.version>
<hadoop.version>hadoop2-1.9.17</hadoop.version>
<google-cloud.version>1.135.2</google-cloud.version>
<spark-bigquery_2.12.version>0.19.0</spark-bigquery_2.12.version>

basically this spark connector version should be only worked in local mode, as when submitting the job in Google DataProc, will give a parameter to set it as gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar.
This code works on VM 2.0-debian10, but when upgrading the version to 2.2-debian12, will get this error.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider could not be instantiated
error code direct to above line I provided.
and casued by
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:  This connector was made for Scala null, it was not meant to run on Scala 2.12


Could you add more details about how you build or pack the job, what's the build tool you are using (sbt, maven, gradle), config file for building the project (build.sbt, pom.xml, build.gradle), what's the command you run to submit/run the job? The links from spark BigQuery connector README, doesn't match with the one you shared.

When submit the dataproc job, will pass a jar_file parameter to provide the spark-connector like this "jar_files":["gs://[$bucket-code]/fotc-mi/jars/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.8.8.jar","gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar"]

I'm using Maven to build the package without dependencies. Added some properties in the pom file to add the libs like
<scala.version>2.12.1</scala.version>
<scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
<jsonpath.version>2.4.0</jsonpath.version>
<hadoop-core.version>1.2.1</hadoop-core.version>
<hadoop.version>hadoop2-1.9.17</hadoop.version>
<google-cloud.version>1.135.2</google-cloud.version>
<spark-bigquery_2.12.version>0.19.0</spark-bigquery_2.12.version>


emmm <spark-bigquery_2.12.version>0.19.0</spark-bigquery_2.12.version> As you can see I use the spark connector version 0.19.0 in the pom.xml file, but I'm not using the assembly plugin to package the dependencies for the jar package. So when submitting the job, I will give that jar_files parameter to set the connector again.

Please edit your post with the information you detailed in the comments using the right formatting. If it is possible, try to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Dataproc on GCE 2.1+ images pre-install Spark BigQquery connector: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-release-2.2
To fix this issues you need to remove (or mark as provided) Spark BigQuery connector from dependencies in your Spark application pom.xml.

I followed @Igor Dvorzhak instructions. However, it was necessary to remove BigQuery jar as DataProc parameter.
This worked for me.

It's not a "thank you" answer.
I am informing that the solution from @Igor Dvorzhak did not work for me.
It was necessary removing BigQuery jar when starting DataProc job.
Then it worked.
